# howto set android titleicon to downloaded image

Tags: android

Is it possible to set the icon in the android title dynamically to an icon downloaded from the internet?

I only find ways of setting it to in icon in the Resources.

I am writing an app used by different companies/apartments and I want to dynamically customize the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use productFlavour in-app level Gradle and change the application icon to different clients. They are stored locally. I am not sure about downloading it from the internet and you should add this in manifest

```
tools:replace="android:icon"
```

Comment: ProductFlavors Are Set at compile time, are they not?

Comment: Yes, as you said you giving it to different companies/apartments you could give a different apk with a different icon. If you are using single apk then this approach will not fit.

Comment: Well, I guess there is not way